# git push branch is already checked out; then needs working directory after bare

Tags: git

I'm having a hard time understanding this one ; pretty much all I've found via stack overflow and blogs seem to imply that using `--bool core.bare true` solves the issue but I believe there's something missing.

Example:

```
"cd $HOME"
git init thing

cd existingrepo
git remote add origin "$HOME/thing"
git push origin master
```

Doing this, I get an error `! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)`

I've found answers that basically say, go to `thing/` and run

```
git config --bool core.bare true
```

When I do that, I can indeed push, but when I go to `thing/` again, it's in a weird state - there are no files, and doing git-status I am told

```
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

so I reverse the bool operation

```
git config --bool core.bare true
git status
```

and I find that the changes are there, but there have also been `delete` stages

```
~/thing$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        deleted:    .gitignore
        deleted:    registry.py
        deleted:    static/css/normalize.css
        deleted:    static/css/skeleton.css
```

I can only resolve this by performing a `git reset --hard` at which point my `thing/` repository matches my original repository.

(I'm doing this with local folders, but the same behavious happens over SSH, which is my target workflow - basic SSH-based repos)

Can somebody enlighten me here please?

Comment: For clarity I was expecting the `thing` repo to hold its git data in a `.git` dir like a normal cloned repo.

Answer (score 1):

Hello can you please try to delete your 'thing' repo and reinit it with `git init --bare thing.git`. You don't need to run `git config --bool core.bare true`

Comment: The contents on the server become a literal .git content rather than a repo with checked out files and the git data in a .git directory.... none of the "duplicates" address the model i am attempting ... or is what i am doing an antipattern, and why?